# <!DOCTYPE html> in JS file

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, token

I am referencing two JS files in my map.HTML header. Chrome console gives

```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Here is why I'm confused. When I click on the Chrome Console error message, it takes me to the Sources tab. Under Sources, it puts me on the relative JS tab, and shows code starting with < !DOCTYPE html> then continues with a ton of code that is not in my map.html file or JS file. Presumably this is generated when the JS is read?

The two JS files are:

https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/tree/master/dist
https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/tree/gh-pages/dist

I am opening map.HTML locally with Chrome using a simple python server using a batch file (python.exe -m http.server).

I am sure this is very basic, but it's confusing me because I reference plenty of other JS files both online and locally and I don't get this error.

Thanks

Comment: HTML can be found on codepen here:  https://codepen.io/LeevGG/pen/OjVMJM

Comment: Javascript files don't start with `<!DOCTYPE ...>`. The urls you're referencing aren't Javascript files either.

Comment: js doesn't use `<!DOCTYPE html>` or doctype at all... this is for html..

Comment: The JS syntax for what <!DOCTYPE html> in HTML does is "use strict" :)

Comment: Apologies, was getting confused looking at the Console message vs. JS file and misstated. I've revised my comment.

Comment: Note https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/tree/master/dist and  https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/tree/gh-pages/dist are not files but directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/blob/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js in your browser, you will get an HTML page.

If you try https://raw.githubusercontent.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js you will get what seams a source javascript file. But your browser may also consider it text/html, because that's what github sends in content-type header.

You can use third party sites which will serve files with appropriate content-type header, (example: https://rawgit.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js ).

Comment: I had tried the rawgit.com approach after researching online (a lot), but I wasn't sure it was loading properly. Console highlighted the link in red and labeled it GET (in red), suggesting to me there was still an issue with loading it.  What really confuses me is why these two cause issues when others did not. What is unique about them?

Comment: This got my JS loading but it still labels it in RED in the Console. Guess I will do some reading up on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, try to do more research before posting here, otherwise a lot of people are going to downvote your questions, and even insult you.

A simple Google search for the differences between html and javascript may be a good start. The first step would be to remove those doctype lines. They mean nothing in Javascript. Just like the word `granola` has no meaning in Japanese. Different languages.

However, looking at your code, I don't see any `DOCTYPE` text in your javascript. In order to really debug this, you're going to want to open your webpage (html) in a browser (I recommend Chrome) and press F12 to open the developer tools. Go to the console and trace the error back through all of the files to find the origin.

In order to check and make sure that you're trying to pull javascript files and not html, take all the `src` urls you're using and paste them in a browser. If you land on a webpage, that url will serve up html, not javascript like you want. If you get a wall of text, you're probably referencing it correctly.

Correct: https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.js

Incorrect: https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/blob/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js

Hopefully this helps before this question gets deleted or put on hold. Also notice that people are going to downvote me for actually answering and trying to help.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I have been doing and updated my post accordingly.

Comment: This is a bit more complicated because you're using the codepen website, which doesn't like the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration

Comment: I loaded it there as reference for the question. I am not using it to test.

Comment: Tough day @toshiomagic ? :) I think you should edit your questions and remove what isn't relevant to the OP problem.

Comment: I feel that warning a new user about the culture here is more helpful than the answer to this question. Look at this. A new user and programmer genuinely looking for help gets a -4 (so far) on a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly reference code stored in a github repo like you're trying to.

The URLs you're listing aren't javascript files; they're github webpages. That's why they contain HTML doctypes and code you don't recognize -- it's the github website code.

You can get the URL for the actual javascript files by clicking the "raw" button at the top of any of those pages (after selecting a specific individual file -- the urls you gave were for directories, not individual files.)  For example:

This is an HTML file: https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/blob/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js

This is the raw javascript:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js

(That said, I don't believe it's a good idea to treat github like a CDN; usually you would use that purely as a repository and host the actual files in use elsewhere.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. I wasn't sure of the best way to reference JS hosted on Github and had yet to find consistent 'best practice' advice online (and written for a complete rookie).